# Nextjs 13 slow load on windows server

Tags: node.js, iis, next.js, next.js13

I have a next js app on a windows server. I'm using a url rewrite reverse proxy so the default website leads to localhost:3000 where my app is running using `npm run start`. After I run `npm run build` the file sizes are small enough:

```
Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      3.83 kB         193 kB
├ ○ /page-1                                22.3 kB         200 kB
├ λ /page-2/[slug]                         18.6 kB         155 kB
├ ○ /favicon.ico                           0 B                0 B
├ ○ /industry                              402 B           143 kB
├ λ /page-3/[slug]                         3.59 kB         217 kB
├ ○ /search                                4.39 kB         218 kB
└ λ /page-4                                7.25 kB         173 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              77.9 kB
  ├ chunks/698-9aeb085986fa3c35.js         25.3 kB
  ├ chunks/bce60fc1-4fb1d7d66adc126a.js    50.5 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-81baf2622b02bba0.js    221 B
  └ chunks/webpack-9a9ff32ad7229fde.js     1.9 kB

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
─ ○ /404                                   183 B          75.9 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              75.7 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-43665103d101a22d.js   45.1 kB
  ├ chunks/main-35a40e64711e27bc.js        28.5 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-4e72088c2da7d84b.js  198 B
  └ chunks/webpack-9a9ff32ad7229fde.js     1.9 kB
```

When I try to access the website I get the following load time and file sizes:

```
116 requests
19.85 MB / 3.98 MB transferred
Finish: 42.20 s
DOMContentLoaded: 5.99 s
load: 20.71 s
```

layout.js is 6.73MB, main-app.js is 6.1MB ...
I need to know what I'm doing wrong, why is the app so slow that it takes 42s to finish loading a single page?

Comment: Provide a repo.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description. When the server hangs, crashes or performance is low, 
it is usually necessary to grab the server's thread stack (Thread Dump) for subsequent analysis. 
So I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, 
there will be professional technicians to assist you in grabbing the dump file and analyzing it.